# How to access the fields of an object in java?

Tags: java, io

I apologize, this question has already been answered once. However, the solution didn't help me.

I made a program working with an `ArrayList` containing name,ID and country. However, I cannot access the name, ID and country on their own, only their object as a whole. I tried using `animal.name` and I get the error `name cannot be resolved or is not a field`. I tried using methods like `getName()` to return the name of the object, but I got the error `The method getName() is undefined for the type ArrayList<ANIMAL>`. Would you please help me with that?

This is the class which, when called, creates a new object inside the `ArrayList` and `fields` of which I'm trying to access:

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class ANIMAL implements Serializable {
        String nameA;
        String IDA;
        String countryA;

        public ANIMAL(String name, String ID, String country){
            nameA = name;
            String IDA = ID;
            String countryA = country;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return nameA;
        }
        public String getCountry(){
            return countryA;
        }
        public String getID(){
            return IDA;
        }
        }
```

Comment: You can get an animal from your list using (for instance) `list.get(0)`. You can get the name of that animal using `list.get(0).getName()`. You have to access the properties via the object inside the list, not via the list itself.

Comment: It looks you are trying to learn programming Java. There are some things you should have an eye on: Class names in Java are CamelCase. Property names should start with a lower case. In your constructor you are defining two new String variables instead of assigning the values to the class properties. And (one guess from my side) your class properties have strange names like nameA. You don't have to use the A at the end when want the construtor to work. You just have to do this.name = name when the class property and the constructor argument have the same name.

Comment: I apologize for my mistakes, especially the definitions of two new string variables. I was messing with the code beforehand and I was so tired, I forgot to delete them... Thank you both for your answers, I will keep these in mind next time I write code. khelwood, if I was to use `list.get(i).getName()` inside a loop, how would I do it if I don't know how many objects my `ArrayList` has? `while ( list.get(i).getName() != null )` ?

Comment: Beowulf: it looks like, once this was solved, you overwrote the question with the solution. We don't do that here. Obviously, this leaves us with two answers an no question, rather than a question followed by an answer. Since we like to use Q&A pairs to help _future_ readers, we prefer if the question can remain undisturbed - I have therefore rolled it back. Don't forget to accept the answer below you found most helpful, thanks.

Comment: I apologize for the inconveniences, I will keep it in mind next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animal class:

```
public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String country;

    public Animal (String name, String id, String country){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Pseudo application class (with main method for starting the application):

```
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Animal("British Bulldog", "12345", "UK"));
        list.add(new Animal("Boston Terrier", "12346", "USA"));
        list.add(new Animal("German Shepherd", "12347", "Germany"));
        // this is a for-each loop but basically you just need
        // to get an item from the list, list.get(i) would suffice
        for (Animal a: list) {
            System.out.println(a.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
British Bulldog
Boston Terrier
German Shepherd
```

Also: I took the liberty of tidying up your code to match conventions, look at the differences and try to understand them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this solved all my problems. Precise answer and code, no questions unanswered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor was flawed.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ANIMAL implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String ID;
    String country;

    public ANIMAL(String name, String ID, String country){
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID; 
        // String IDA = ID; doesn't assigns param ID to field ID of the class
        this.country = country; //same
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }
    public String getID(){
        return ID;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Have a nice day!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote yet, otherwise I would have upvoted every comment. I gave the badge "most helpful answer" to Neilos, because he was first to comment, although your solution is correct too. Sorry, all I can do right now is thank you.

Comment: Fine. Have a nice day!